# ¿Cómo busco con regex cadenas que terminen por una extensión?

Tags: python, regex

Mi expresión regular es:

```
    patron = '.qvw'
```

Invoco así el regex:

```
 if re.match(patron, fich):
                if fich.lower().endswith(patron.lower()):
                    print(patron + " 2 -----> " + fich.lower())
```

Tengo este listado donde tengo que buscar por patron `re`:

```
SIN%20INCIDENCIA%20RESINA.QVW.Shared
ServerCounters.pgo
RESINASEPT.QVW.Shared
Resinasept.qvw
RESINAFORMACION.QVW.Shared
RESINA_REDUCIDO.QVW.Shared
RESINA_BACK.QVW.Shared
RESINA_11.QVW.Shared
RESINA_.QVW.Shared
Resina.qvw.Shared
Resina.qvw.Meta
Resina.qvw
RESINA-OLD-28-03-2017.QVW.Shared
RESINA%20V13.0%20REDUCIDA.QVW.Shared
RESINA%20V12.0.QVW.Shared
RESINA%20V10.0.QVW.Shared
RESINA%20REDUCIDO.QVW.Shared
RESINA%20REDU.QVW.Shared
RESINA%20REDU%20MALO.QVW.Shared
RESINA%20PRUEBA%20RECARGA%20SERVIDOR.QVW.Shared
RESINA%20PRODUCCI%C3%93N.QVW.Shared
Resina%20producci%C3%B3n.qvw
RESINA%20PRODUCCI%C3%93N%20SEPTIEMBRE.QVW.Shared
RESINA%20PRODUCCI%C3%93N%20MAYO%283%20MODULOS%20COMPLETO%29.QVW.Shared
RESINA%20PRODUCCI%C3%93N%20JULIO.QVW.Shared
RESINA%20PRODUCCI%C3%93N%20ANTERIOR.QVW.Shared
RESINA%20PRODUCCI%C3%93N%20ABRIL%283%20MODULOS%20COMPLETO%29.QVW.Shared
RESINA%20PRODUCCION.QVW.Shared
RESINA%20PRODUCCION%20MAYO.QVW.Shared
RESINA%20MODULOS%204%20Y%205.QVW.Shared
```

Debería de coger solo .qvw como puedo omitir que me acepte:

```
RESINA%20REDU.QVW.Shared 
RESINA%20REDU%20MALO.QVW.Shared
```

es decir que solo acepte .qvw en minusculas

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que me coja solo los que acaban en .qvw?

Comment: ¿cómo invocas al regex? ¿Estás seguro que no le estás pasando `IGNORECASE`?

Comment: Además de lo comentado por @jachguate, ten en cuenta que `.` significa `cualquier caracter salvo salto de línea` con lo que probablemente debieras escaparlo con `\.` o `[.]`. Creo que en tu caso no te afectaba, pero te podrías haber encontrado un fichero con `aqvw` y te hubiera hecho un match

Comment: Tengo que añadir el ignore case supongo ¿verdad?

Comment: habia pensado probar con este patron para el regex                                                           patron = [a-zA-Z_]*\.qvw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No necesitas una expresión regular si lo único que quieres es mirar la extensión de un fichero, basta usar `.endswith()` (y por supuesto no pasar a minúsculas con `.lower()` el nombre del fichero, si quieres que sea sensitivo al *case*).

Por ejemplo, suponiendo que en la `mis_nombres` cada elemento es un nombre de fichero a verificar:

```
extension = ".qvw"
for fich in mis_nombres:
    if fich.endswith(extension):
        print(extension + " 2 -----> " + fich)
```

Si insistes en usar expresiones regulares, la correcta sería la siguiente:

```
import re
patron = r".*\.qvw$"
for fich in mis_nombres:
    if re.match(patron, fich):
        print(extension + " 2 -----> " + fich)
```

La expresión regular `.*\.qvw$` significa:

- `.` Cualquier carácter
- `*` repetido cero o más veces
- `\.` seguido de un punto (la barra delante es para evitar que signifique "cualquier caracter")
- `qvw` seguido de la cadena qvw
- `$` seguido del final de cadena (es decir, que "qvw" sea lo último que aparece en la cadena)